# Qlikview GetFieldSelections Multiple Selection

Tags: qlikview

I have a list box that selects distinct values (one of three) from a `listbox`.

This then filters a chart where I show a bar chart based on sum totals.

Currently, it works when one value is selected from the `listbox`, I require the chart to work with more than one selection (i.e. Two out of the three or Three out of Three) however the syntax used doesn't work.

Here is the line I'm using for selection in the chart Properties, Expression

```
Sum ( {< Bank_Division = {'$(=GetFieldSelections(BU))'} >} Amt_Requested)
```

I'm guessing its connected to the `GetFieldSelections` method however all answers seem so far suggest concatenation as a replacement, I don't see how this would resolve my requirement.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think the problem is that when multiple values are selected in your listbox, `'$(=GetFieldSelections())'` will resolve to a string like `'value1, value3, value3'` when what you need is a comma separated list of strings like `'value1', 'value2', 'value3'`. Is there a reason why you cannot simply make selections in a listbox for `Bank_Division`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want to do you should use this expression

```
=chr(39)&concat(distinct FieldB,chr(39)&','&chr(39))&chr(39)
```

and then your set analysis looks like this

```
Sum ( {< Bank_Division = {'$(=concat(distinct BU,chr(39)&','&chr(39)))'}>} >} Amt_Requested)
```

As mentioned the getfieldselections() function returns values with a '$(=GetFieldSelections(BU))' will result in 'value1,value2' which set analysis can't use. It needs a comma separated list with single quotes for each value not defining the ends of the list.

The concat function will result in 'value1','value2'. The chr(39) is just a trick to insert the inverted commas into the output of the expression rather than have them act as part of the expression definition. The distinct is necessary because concat() returns every possible value unless you tell it to only bring unique values.

Another reason to use concat() rather than the getfieldselections() is that when nothing is selected getfieldselections will come back as undefined,  concat returns the list of possible values at all times, honouring other selections that might limit that list. So it really behaves like the native QlikView engine.

That last statement is why you should think carefully about whether you need this in  your expression or if you can just let QlikView do what it does as the overhead, especially if you need to distinct a long list is potentially quite high for something that the program is built to do on it's own anyway.

The only time I've done this is when using if() causes data integrity issues because of complex data models and even then it was really as a quick fix until I went back to fix the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks so much @The Budac,
I had a list of items where some of the items had commas in them, and i couldn't find a solution, this one breaks items themselves: '"' & Replace(GetFieldSelections(country), ', ', '","') & '"'.
That caused so much trouble, and your solution is actually the perfect one, thank you!